# proper way to handle dynamic responses by retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, authentication, jwt, retrofit2

let's say I've got a REST API which I could get list of books by invoking following retrofit 2 request.

```
public interface AllRecordsFromRequestInterface {
    @GET("books/all")
    Call<List<TrackInfo>> operation(@Header("Authorization") String   authentication_token);
}
```

and API response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "The Catcher in the Rye",
    "author":"J. D. Salinger"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "The Great Gatsby",
    "author":"F. Scott Fitzgerald"
  }
]
```

I use `GsonConverterFactory` to convert json to a Model. here is my model class

```
public class Book{
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
}
```

I'm using a authentication token to authorize myself to API as it can be seen in my request. some times other response are received rather than above response because of token expiration or something else. for example:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Expired token"
}
```

what is the proper way to handle dynamic responses (with known structure) in retrofit 2?

Comment: If your token has expired the api should return you an error code 401. And you can go from there. If it returns 200 and some error payload then it is incorrectly designed api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have multiple choices:

1-change your API:(this one is standard)

change it like this for every response and if the user failed with authentication leave the result null or if authentication was successful put the list in the result.

```
{
"status" : "error/success"
"message" : ...
"result" : ....
}
```

2- you can give Object type to retrofit and after the response was successful you can cast it to one of your models, using "instance of" syntax.

```
public interface AllRecordsFromRequestInterface {
@GET("books/all")
Call<Object> operation(@Header("Authorization") String authentication_token);
}
```